# Multiple operations in map method using streams in Java8

Tags: lambda, java-8

Given list of customers, I need to create another list with first names of customers in upper case. This is the code in java-

```
List<String> getFirstNames(List<Customer> customers)
{
    List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Customer customer: customers) {
        firstNames.add(StringUtils.uppercase(customer.getFirstName());
    }
    return firstNames;
}
```

How do I write this method using lambda in java8.
I could use streams in this way, to convert to list-

```
customers.stream().map(Customer::getFirstName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, how can I convert firstName to upper case, using this?

Comment: With method references `customers.stream().map(Customer::getFirstName).map(StringUtils::uppercase).collect(toList());`

Comment: Any reason to use `StringUtils.uppercase(customer.getFirstName())` instead of simply `customer.getFirstName().toUpperCase()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Shouldn't we prefer to do it in one line as in the answer instead of doing it in 2 iterations?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to write your own lambda expression that does the conversion to uppercase for you:

```
 List<String> firstNames = customers.stream()
                         .map(customer->StringUtils.uppercase(customer.getFirstName()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Even in your code you are taking the customer name and then doing toUpperCase.

```
      List<String> firstNames = customers.stream()
                    .map(customer-> customer.getFirstName())
                    .map(firstName -> StringUtils.uppercase(firstName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```